# Telerik WPF QueryableCollectionView FilterDescriptors CollectionChanged event not firing

Tags: wpf, mvvm, telerik, filtering, radgridview

We have a standard WPF MVVM project.  In one view model we have a QueryableCollectionView to which a radgridview is bound.  When the user filters the grid we had expected the QueryableCollectionView.FilterDescriptors.CollectionChanged to be fired but nothing is happening.  When we inspect the FilterDescriptors through visual studio we can see the collection is present.  Is this binding incorrect or am I missing something else?

Any help appreciated:

```
DisplayTrades = new QueryableCollectionView(displayTradeSource, typeof(TradeViewModel));
DisplayTrades.FilterDescriptors.CollectionChanged += collectionChanged_Event;

private void CollectionChanged_Event(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
           throw Exception("test");
}
```